# Embed Webpage into website using an Iframe

Tags: php, iframe, x-frame-options

I'm trying to embed a webpage of mine within my website portfolio to showcase skills etc. However most browsers throw an error

> Refused to display 'url' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'.

I know this is because my server has a set of xframe options assigned to it.

What other options are there to run a webpage within a webpage, or are there any work arounds to the xframe origins?

Comment: Get your site (the one you're trying to embed) not to output the x-frame-options header. It's your site, so presumably you can control what headers it outputs. Bear in mind of course that this would then allow _anyone_ to embed your site inside theirs, which may or may not be desirable.

Comment: See also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options

Comment: Alternatively you should use the [frame-ancestors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/frame-ancestors) content security policy to allow the site to be embedded, but only into your portfolio site

Comment: Just to give another perspective, as I’m one of the people that portfolios such as this are targeted towards: don’t embed, just link. You can include some screenshots of how it was, if you want, too, but I don’t need or want to be frame-locked.

Comment: Are you sure this problem is in any way related to PHP? Usually, PHP doesn't care about iFrames